# App meta data rejected , requires demo account

Tags: ios, facebook, metadata

My app has been rejected because i needed to put a demo account in the meta data, my app is facebook login based , we store users facebook id and create a customerID on its basis , since there is no password i don't know what to write in the demo account meta data .

apple response

We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because we need a demo account to fully access your app features.

Please provide demo account details in the Review Notes section of the Version Information for your app. Please ensure that the information you provide includes any data necessary to demonstrate the functionality of your app features.

Specifically, upon review we found that a demo account is required for testing and functionality of application.

Comment: Create a demo Facebook account and give them that username/password?

Answer (score 2):

While submitting the metadata of the application there is a field called "Demo Account Information". You should create an facebook account and you should pass the details of this account into this section. This will enable Apple guys to test your application. They will not verify your application with their facebook Ids. So, provide proper credentials in above section.